# What is the substitute of CanvasAuthorizeAttribute in FaceBook C# SDK 6.4 version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk

In MVC3, we could use the **CanvasAuthorize Attribute(in old FaceBook version)** properties like LoginDisplayMode , ReturnUrlPath ,CancelUrlPath.

How can we use them in Latest version 6.4?

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "", LoginDisplayMode = "popup", 
                  ReturnUrlPath = "Some Url", CancelUrlPath = "Some Url")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

We have `[FacebookAuthorize("Permissions")]` in the MVC4. But, how we could use other properties like *LoginDisplayMode , ReturnUrlPath ,CancelUrlPath*. as mentioned above ?

[image]

### **[I have gone through this article at GitHub. But no help so far](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/144)**

### **[I have read this article suggested by Prabir. But no help so far](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There is no provision for the **Named parameter** of `CanvasAuthorize Attribute` of Older Dll present in the `FacebookAuthorize Attribute` of the latest version.*

**[Please check this link for more details](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/278)**

**[Here is the another link](http://xdownload.us/what-is-the-substitute-of-canvasauthorizeattribute-in-facebook-c-sdk-6-4-version/)**

Right now we are provided one overload constructor.

[image]

Comment: at 91, you havent lost a step

Answer (score 2):

Facebook.Web.Mvc has been removed in v6. Please use the Facebook application template that comes in ASP.NET tools.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

Comment: I have the properties in CanvasAthorize Attribute like these        [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ""
, LoginDisplayMode = "popup", ReturnUrlPath = "", CancelUrlPath = "")] How can we use these properties in mvc4 facebook template. can u please give an example ?

Comment: Hi Prabir, Can you kindly share your view on the updated request ?